# Orchard 1.6 VS publish issue

Tags: visual-studio, orchardcms

When publishing a orchard web site from visual studio 2010/2012 it works to publish in release mode for Orchard 1.5.1 then you get a portable ~50MB site.

But for Orchard 1.6 it does not copy the neccesary files/folders unless you choose Debug mode which is to big to consider uploading sometimes ~800MB , why is this ?

We have reverted to 1.5.1 for the time being...

Comment: I published a 1.6 site in release mode yesterday and did not experience this at all. What exactly did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Strange... We did it as simple as right click web project, choose "publish" , select file system and directory , then click go. That results in a folder with only bin,Media,Refresh.html . No modules or core or templates etc was copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to go to the *Package/Publish Settings* for the *Orchard.Web* project, find option *"Items to deploy"*, and change it's value to *"All files in this project folder"*. Make sure that the current configuration context is set to *Release*.

Currently it's value is set by default to *"Only files needed to run this application"*. As a result, some important sub-directories of the *Orchard.Web*, like *Themes* and *Modules*, are not get published, because they are not included into the project file.

NOTE: In order to decrease generated output folder size you need check option *"Exclude generated debug symbols"* below the *"Items to deploy"*.

BTW, As far as I remember, this issue is relevant for the previous versions too.

As far as I understand, it's more correct to use `build.cmd` file for building deployment package instead of using *Publish* command directly from VS. This way you can also utilize new *Precompiled target* feature, intoduced in Orchard 1.6. It provides ability to precompile all modules and themes, and publish them as DLLs.

Comment: Thanks this was the solution.

Comment: Scratch that...this put all the files there but I still end up with a ~350MB file instead of ~50MB like with version 1.5.1 , I couldn't get the build.cmd working says msbuild is not a recognized function

Comment: Not a good idea. Just make sure that all the files you need *are* included.

Comment: @John, you need to exclude debug files from the output. Please, read my updated answer.

Comment: @John if you want to use *build.cmd*, you must be running it within the context of the Visual Studio Command Prompt

Comment: @s.ermakovich the "Exclude generated debug symbols" didn't help I was doing that previously anyway, also couldn't get the build.cmd to work in VS cmd , but seems I have finally found a solution in this "ClickToBuild.cmd" sounds pretty obvious now.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy Whats not a good idea ? Do you reccomend the cmd files over the publish through VS ? It looks like the "ClickToBuild.cmd" file was exactly what I needed.

Comment: It is not a good idea to uncheck "only files needed to run this application".

Comment: ok I see thanks @BertrandLeRoy and s.ermakovich, marking this post as answer since a found workaround somewhere in here

Comment: The published folder includes .cs files. How to publish the folders without .cs files?